# Babel не компилирует проект с ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babel

У меня вебпак не собирает проект, написанный с фичами ES6 и реактом. Конфиг вебпака такой:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "css-loader" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Я получаю ошибку:

```
ERROR in ./src/TodoForm.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (16:11)

  14 |   }
  15 | 
> 16 |   onChange = (event) => {
     |            ^
  17 |     this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
  18 |   }
  19 |
```

Как я понимаю, бабелю не нравится стрелочный синтаксис, он не может это распарсить. Какие плагины надо подключить, чтобы бабель все это скомпилировал??

Comment: Я думаю проблема не в babel. onChange это что ? Функция или переменная?

Comment: @Zicrael, задумано, что это функция. Обработчик событий. Она определена внутри класса TodoForm.

Answer (score 1):

Установи и добавь в `.babelrc` пресет для Babel `stage-0`.

Описание: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0